# Any books similar to Mikrokosmos written by a famous composer?

Tags: piano, keyboard, exercises, sight-reading, teaching

I just discovered this gold nugget in piano teaching called Mikrokosmos by Bela Bartok.

Are there any other books that have progressively difficult sight-reading exercises written by a famous composer? Also, are there any such exercises specifically to train rhythm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schumann's Album for the Young (Album für die Jugend), is a famous example.  Not exercises as such, but simple through to hard self-contained pieces.

You couldn't get much better than the Mikrokosmos to train rhythm.